# How to access mobile data usage from settings in android mobile using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my application i want to access contact names and mobile data usage from Android mobile. I get the contacts list from the mobile by using the below code. But I have no idea how to access mobile data usage from the settings in android mobile. I have referred many sites but none of them could give me a clear answer. How do I access the mobile data usage when mobile data is turned ON?

```
var context = MainActivity.GetAppContext();

var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.HasPhoneNumber 
};

var cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

ObservableCollection<UserContact> UserContactList = new 
ObservableCollection<UserContact>();

cursor.MoveToFirst();
```

Comment: I think you might have to call web service for the cell phone provider to get this info

Answer (score 0):

You can query only basic info using the `Android.Net.TrafficStats` class:

```cs
var receivedTotal = Android.Net.TrafficStats.MobileRxBytes;
var transmittedTotal = Android.Net.TrafficStats.MobileTxBytes;

//app-specific
var uid = Android.OS.Process.MyUid();
var receivedByApp = Android.Net.TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(uid);
var transmittedByApp = Android.Net.TrafficStats.GetUidTxBytes(uid);
```

Please note that the app-specific methods return overall number of bytes since the network interface or app started and may be zeroed-out when connection drops or app closes. Also they count not only mobile data, but include wi-fi connection as well.

There is no built-in API to query mobile data usage of other apps in the default API. Some manufacturers might offer their own implementations for this, but it is not available in the "clean Android OS".

Comment: When i disconnect the mobile data or wifi, received and transmitted bytes are still showing. The transmitted and received bytes value are varies little bit only.